# Why is TypeScript complaining when using pnpm?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, yarnpkg, pnpm

I'm trying to migrate from `yarn` to `pnpm` but I've hit a bit of an issue and I'm not sure where to go with it. I haven't tried changing the settings around hoisting yet (I'd prefer not to if possible), but I'm trying to understand why this is causing me a problem.

I've got a small utility function which works fine when using yarn:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

export const useAlertConfigurationNameStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    name: {
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
    },
}));
```

If I switch over to `pnpm` I get the following error:

```
  Overload 1 of 2, '(style: Styles<Theme, {}, "name">, options?: Pick<WithStylesOptions<Theme>, "link" | "index" | "media" | "name" | "meta" | "flip" | "element" | "defaultTheme" | "generateId" | "classNamePrefix">): (props?: any) => ClassNameMap<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(theme: Theme) => { name: { fontWeight: FontWeight; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Styles<Theme, {}, "name">'.
      Type '(theme: Theme) => { name: { fontWeight: FontWeight; }; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleRulesCallback<Theme, {}, "name">'.
        Call signature return types '{ name: { fontWeight: FontWeight; }; }' and 'StyleRules<{}, "name">' are incompatible.
          The types of 'name' are incompatible between these types.
            Type '{ fontWeight: Property.FontWeight; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | CreateCSSProperties<{}> | PropsFunc<{}, CreateCSSProperties<{}>>'.
              Type '{ fontWeight: Property.FontWeight; }' is not assignable to type 'CreateCSSProperties<{}>'.
                Types of property 'fontWeight' are incompatible.
                  Type 'FontWeight' is not assignable to type 'FontWeightProperty | PropsFunc<{}, FontWeightProperty>'.
                    Type 'string & {}' is not assignable to type 'FontWeightProperty | PropsFunc<{}, FontWeightProperty>'.
                      Type 'string & {}' is not assignable to type '"lighter"'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(styles: Styles<Theme, {}, "name">, options?: Pick<WithStylesOptions<Theme>, "link" | "index" | "media" | "name" | "meta" | "flip" | "element" | "defaultTheme" | "generateId" | "classNamePrefix">): (props: {}) => ClassNameMap<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(theme: Theme) => { name: { fontWeight: FontWeight; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Styles<Theme, {}, "name">'.
      Type '(theme: Theme) => { name: { fontWeight: FontWeight; }; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleRulesCallback<Theme, {}, "name">'.

  3 export const useAlertConfigurationNameStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  4     name: {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
  6     },
    ~~~~~~
  7 }));
    ~~



Found 1 error.
```

Both are using the same version of `@material-ui/core` which is included in the `package.json`.

Does anyone know what the cause might be, or how I go about investigating more? I'm not all that familiar with TypeScript so not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried to run the command `pnpm install`?

Comment: @Tkim yes, I've installed :)

Comment: it seems compiler complains to useAlertConfigurationNameStyles and in your example there is useStyles function if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov sorry, I've updated. I tried to refactor out the name for the question as it's not relevant. Forgot about the error though!

Comment: I don't know why but when you can't fix something as a last resort you can always just set [`node-linker=hoisted`](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#node-linker).

Comment: Have you solved this somehow? I have the same issue. Yarn gives me no errors at all and pnpm gives me 100 errors in 33 files on the same codebase...

Comment: @Belovoj I did eventually solve it, I should have put an answer in here. I believe it was because two different libraries were requiring different versions of React and the types were conflicting. I think I had to use a custom module resolution to fix it

Comment: thanks for the answer, I found mine too, I was importing a Request object from the wrong module. The funny thing is it was in the old code and Typescript didn't find it using yarn...

Comment: Can either of you share the code you used? I'm having a rough time fixing my issue.

Comment: @FarzadSoltani if you ask a new question and link here (or reach out on pnpm discord) I can try and help

Comment: @Ian Thanks. I couldn't find you on the discord channel. But I managed to fix it by re-enabling `strictNullChecks` in my `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

You might experience this issue because of tsconfig.json options. Make sure you set declaration and declaratonMap to false

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "declarationMap": false,
  (...)
 }
```